# Latex expressions shown in a terminal

Tags: terminal, graphics, latex, lxterminal

Is there any way to show a graphic Latex expression in a (textual) terminal? Particularly, can an LXTerminal show the rendering of a Latex equation? Alternatively, is there any terminal emulator that allows it?

Note: This question is posted here because the problem focuses on the terminal itself, not on the rendering process.

Comment: Do you want the formula to appear as an image or as text?

Comment: Graphically, the rendering of the equation itself. Without opening extra windows, in the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminology is the way to go to display images in terminal emulators. In ttys, the framebuffer is available too.

`tex2im` provides a nice solution to convert formulas as images but has drawbacks which may be problematic depending on your usecase. It puts an `out.png` file in your current directory, accept only math, etc.

Here is a similar but somewhat more customizable approach:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1

cd $dir
cat <<EOF > file.tex
\\documentclass[varwidth=true,border=5pt]{standalone}
\\begin{document}
$1
\\end{document}
EOF

texfot --quiet --interactive  pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex && \
convert -density 600 file.pdf -quality 90 -background white -alpha off -resize 50% file.png && \
tycat $dir/file.png && \
sleep 0.5
rm -r $dir
```

It uses the package `standalone` to produce a PDF the right size and then convert it with ImageMagick. Actually, `standalone` can handle the transformation but do not allow all the options ImageMagick accepts.

All the file are created in a temporary directory. It's necessary to wait a little before removing it in order not to race with `tycat` which displays the picture in the terminal.

Example of use:
[image: Example of use of the script]

Comment: It is worth noting that this solution demands installation of `imagemagick`, `texlive-latex-extra`, `texlive-extra-utils`. `tex2im`, in principle, did not demand additional stuff for a fresh Lubuntu installation.